# Transfer records between database with overlap ID (Primary Key)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My current project need to transfer data between databases. The scenario is that I have two different database, they have the similar schema for tables but the information inside table is completely different.
I want to transfer one record from one database to the other, and completely removed it in the old database once transferred. I realize that the primary key for that record may overlap with the one inside the new database.
I think of many solutions: I can add a character in front of the id to distinguish data from different table, then how can I add the character (for example B1100) in front of the id when I transfer? Or how do I automatically increase the ID (meaning generating new ID with the correct order in the new database).

For example: TABLE1 and TABLE2. TABLE1 has the most recent ID is 2000, and I want to transfer a record from TABLE2 with the ID is also 2000. Is there a way that I can transfer that record from table2 with table2.ID is 2000 to a new record of TABLE1 with table1.ID is 2001?

Thank you!

I am planning to use this SQL Query for transferring:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_1.dbo.table1
SELECT *
FROM DATABASE_2.dbo.table2
WHERE DATABASE_2.dbo.table2.id = currentID;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Firstly (if talking SQL Server) you should always list your columns on insert. Secondly you almost never use `select *`. So once you correct those 2 issues, whats stopping you from using `select id + 1, col1, col2 ...`?

Comment: Post DDL for the target table. Typically a column with a name like "id" will be both numeric and an identity. In such cases, "add the character" is not possible. In addition, you must also factor in related rows in other tables. Did you consider that? ETL is generally not nearly as simple as you might think - it requires more than a basic understanding of SQL. Considering getting local help. A subquery can be used to get the current maximum value of ID in your target table.